# Spring Oauth2 JdbcTokenStore Oracle Database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2

i'm trying convert the jdbctoken store schema here
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql

to

```
CREATE TABLE EISBIT.OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN
(
  TOKEN_ID           VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  TOKEN              CLOB,
  AUTHENTICATION_ID  VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  USER_NAME          VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  CLIENT_ID          VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  AUTHENTICATION     CLOB,
  REFRESH_TOKEN      VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)
)
```

ths

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
}
```

but i get this exception when try a

```html
2015-07-03 14:34:01.300  WARN 10952 --- [pr-8080-exec-13] o.s.s.o.p.token.store.JdbcTokenStore     : Failed to deserialize access token for b14fa3b1-5a5a-4d0c-9112-416997c2dc83

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00540001
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.util.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:40)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore.deserializeAccessToken(JdbcTokenStore.java:397)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore$2.mapRow(JdbcTokenStore.java:162)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore$2.mapRow(JdbcTokenStore.java:1)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:708)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:811)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore.readAccessToken(JdbcTokenStore.java:160)
```

error when try to read the tokenstore :(..

Comment: The field is a `LONGVARBINARY` which is a `BLOB` not a `CLOB`. But shouldn't oracle just support `LONGVARBINARY`? Why did you change it to a CLOB in the first place?

Comment: after update driver to latest want it fixxed

Answer (score 1):

modify CLOB to BLOB

```
CREATE TABLE EISBIT.OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN
(
  TOKEN_ID           VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  TOKEN              BLOB,
  AUTHENTICATION_ID  VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  USER_NAME          VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  CLIENT_ID          VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  AUTHENTICATION     BLOB,
  REFRESH_TOKEN      VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same issue.

Visit [this](https://github.com/Abdullah8006/jdbctokenstore_schema_oracle/blob/master/jdbctokenstore_oracle_schema.sql) link if anybody still need the complete working schema.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to map this to RAW or LONG RAW datatype in Oracle .
 We faced this exception and had to change the following fields in OAUTH tables .

1. OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN

   **TOKEN**     RAW

   **AUTHENTICATION**   LONG RAW

   **REFRESH_TOKEN**    RAW
2. OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN

   **TOKEN**   RAW

   **AUTHENTICATION**  LONG RAW